# Node.js: Module does not recognize Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

On `server.coffee` I have:

```
User = mongoose.model 'User', s.UserSchema

addEntryToCustomer = require './lib/addEntryToCustomer'
```

and on `addEntryToCustomer.coffee` I have:

```
module.exports = (phone,res,req) -> 
    User.find {account_id: phone.account_id }, (err, user) ->
```

And I get this error:

```
2011-11-14T19:51:44+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: User is not defined
```

Comment: What are you doing to make sure `User`, defined in `server.coffee`, is visible to `addEntryToCustomer.coffee`?  You're going to need some `module.exports`/`require`.

Answer (score 1):

In node.js, modules run in their own context. That means the `User` variable doesn't exist  in *addEntryToCustomer.coffee*.

You can either make `User` global (careful with it):

```
global.User = mongoose.model 'User'
```

Pass the user variable to the module:

```
module.exports = (User, phone, res, req) -> 
  User.find {account_id: phone.account_id }, (err, user) -> …
```

Or reload the model:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'

module.exports = (phone,res,req) -> 
  User = mongoose.model 'User'
  User.find {account_id: phone.account_id }, (err, user) ->
```

It's also possible to add methods to the Models themselves, though you need to do that when defining the Schema: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/methods-statics.html