# interfacing mongoose with a preexisting mongo collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have looked this up for a while now and I am stuck . I also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794834/how-to-access-a-preexisting-collection-with-mongoose) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127247/node-js-module-does-not-recognize-schema) question and tried it out but I havent been able to get it running.

This is a brief overview of my project: 
I have a python script that parses data from some logs on a server everyday. each log is a python object which is stored in a collection with the corresponding date in db 'stabilitylogs' in mongoDB.

I have now installed node and mongoose and I am trying to pull out this data from a particular collection named - 130702. I am getting the following error:

> C:\node_app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:570
>
> > > throw err;
> > >                     ^
> > >       ReferenceError: Schema is not defined

My stabilitylog.js looks like this:

```
            var mongoose = require('mongoose');
            mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stabilitylogs');

            var db = mongoose.connection;
            db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
            db.once('open', function callback () {
                var rackSchema=new Schema({
                    _id: {type: String },
                    Headend:{
                        Name: String,
                        Rack: {
                            TestInfo:{
                                ScriptStart: String,
                                TotalReboots: String,
                                ScriptLoopCount: String,
                                ScriptName: String,
                                ScriptStop: String,
                                SystemName: String,
                                TotalSTBs: String,
                                PerReboots: String,
                                RunTime: String,
                                BuildVer: String
                                },
                            StbData: [{
                                Status: String,
                                UpTime: String,
                                DBType: String,
                                IP: String,
                                DBVersion: String,
                                RebootData: String,
                                MAC: String,
                                MWApp: String,
                                OS: String
                                },],
                            Number: String
                            }
                        }
                    },
                {collection: '130702'});

                var doc = mongoose.model(rackschema, '130702');
                doc.find();
                });
```

I am really new to this and sure that I have many errors in my code but I really need some help here. 
I am running my entire app on windows 7- installed mongodb ver2.2.4 with the MSI installer and nodeJS - v0.10.12. I installed mongodb and mongoose modules with npm install by writing a package.json file.

Any help is highly appreciated. Also, please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Try `new mongoose.Schema` instead of `new Schema`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK : Thanks. It doesnt seem to work still! :/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you already have `var Schema = mongoose.Schema;` in your file, you need to use `new mongoose.Schema` like JohnnyHK said. In addition the [find method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) on a mongoose model should looks something like this if you want the query to execute immediately.

```
doc.find({}, function(err,collection){ 
//do something with the collection
});
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. :( I tried checking if it is able to pull out data from the db. I get a '0' as the length of collection even though it is not empty. Where am I going wrong? `var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

//connect to db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017//test", function(err, db) {
 if(!err) {
  console.log("we are connected");
  var collection = db.collection('movies');
  
  collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) { console.log(items.length);});
  }
 });`

Comment: sorry for the formatting! I dont know how to edit it properly.